# How do I create a function that generates new variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I know that there might be tons of the same question here, but being a noob I can't really understand them.

What I'd like to do is creating a function that, once we click on a button or simply activate it, it generates a new variable accesible in all the scopes, not overwriting the previous one it generated, with a different name and a value (the value can be a parameter we pass to the function or simply something taken from an array or a Math.random(), it doesn't matter).
The names could be the same for all variables but followed with a _2, _3, _4 etc.

How can I do it as simple as possible?

Would you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Whilst strictly speaking what you're asking can be done (as the `global` object `window` can have named properties added to it, what you really should be using is an array declared in the root scope.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 1;
var prefix = "prefix"

function createVar(value) {
  var name = prefix + count;
  this[name] = value;
  ++count;
}

$("#button").click(function() {
  createVar("one value " + count);
  var name = prefix + (count - 1);
  console.log(window[name]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Now, you have access to `prefix_1` on first click, `prefix_2` on second click,...